# I don't manage to build a Mac disk image using cx_freeze

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I've tried to build a mac disk image through cx_freeze on a windows machine, using the bdist_img command but I get this error : `error: invalid command 'bdist_dmg'`

Anyone has a hint about what the problem could be ? Thanks!

Comment: To make a Mac executable, you need to freeze on a Mac: http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#freezing-for-other-platforms

Comment: Oh. This sucks. Anyway, thanks for answering!